# Firebase returning [object Object] on table and form

Tags: html, firebase, object, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following problem. The code recognizes that there is something and shows all the entries, but not the content, but only displays [object object]. I really want to read everything that is in the category "Sensor" and also all subcategories. But for now I try to read at least 1 entry. I would be very grateful for help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// var f_database    = firebase.database();
var f_database = firebase.database();
var statusSensor = f_database.ref("Sensor");
//value biasa
f_database.ref().on("value", function (snapshot) {
    var suhu = snapshot.child("Sensor/suhu").val();
    var kelembaban = snapshot.child("Sensor/kelembaban").val();
    var gas = snapshot.child("Sensor/gas").val();
    var tayam = snapshot.child("Sensor/tayam").val();
    var mayam = snapshot.child("Sensor/mayam").val();
    var hayam = snapshot.child("Sensor/hayam").val();



    document.getElementById("suhu").innerHTML = suhu + " °C";
    document.getElementById("kelembaban").innerHTML = kelembaban + " %/RH";
    document.getElementById("gas").innerHTML = gas + " PPM";
    document.getElementById("tayam").innerHTML = tayam + " Ekor";
    document.getElementById("mayam").innerHTML = mayam + " Ekor";
    document.getElementById("hayam").innerHTML = hayam + " Ekor";
});

// Dapatkan referensi table
var table = document.getElementById("table_monitoring").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];;

// Memuat Data
statusSensor.on("value", function (data, prevChildKey) {
    var newstatusAlat = data.val();

    var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);


    cell1.innerHTML = newstatusAlat.nomor;
    cell2.innerHTML = newstatusAlat.tanggalwaktu ;
    cell3.innerHTML = newstatusAlat.suhu;
    cell4.innerHTML = newstatusAlat.kelembaban;
    cell5.innerHTML = newstatusAlat.gas;

});
```

This is the Database on Realtime Database Firebase =

```
 { "Sensor" : {
"gas" : {
  "-MapyBUZwyPkJC0Dwkdj" : 2.5E-4,
  "-MapyBwvASH1_59zT4Qw" : 2.5E-4,
  "-MapyCQZ6fZD9U6xticz" : 1.5E-4,
  "-MapyEew16sK_m1dh-ri" : 0.00173,
  "-MapyK9ZCNI2CKkbojKq" : 2.5E-4,
  "-MapyRUwxgjkapEjKD_O" : 1.5E-4,
  "-MapyYa4Zuw1-uG14y2S" : 1.5E-4,
  "-MapyqHQfFDw6HczThU6" : 1.5E-4,
  "-Mapz77nFqvCk4WabOCH" : 1.5E-4
},
"hayam" : 3980,
"kelembaban" : {
  "-MapyBNg5dDL8Y8DETjR" : 89,
  "-MapyBqgX3L6cLeXKamR" : 86,
  "-MapyCKJHtOa4lW_6nIL" : 86,
  "-MapyEIZ658YxeygvTMk" : 87,
  "-MapyJlqji_CLunKn0GQ" : 88,
  "-MapyPBTkwbsSx_wCSST" : 86,
  "-MapyWI7yVBvayGIoFp6" : 86,
  "-MapylaqXdpZgrusRBDp" : 86,
  "-MapyuoHHtkRERpBNoom" : 86
},
"mayam" : 20,
"nomor" : 2,
"suhu" : {
  "-MapyBGo3XG_q_kN6wyD" : 29,
  "-MapyBkpClHVffMmVnMZ" : 29,
  "-MapyCD5yEiCXdb_1aos" : 29,
  "-MapyCkBd5njs67MIRYK" : 29,
  "-MapyH6r5WStcRHBJOF6" : 29,
  "-MapyMfBx_DEWLCKgEgg" : 29,
  "-MapyTvi80TsvZpQKJaa" : 29,
  "-MapyZZZEH3bfOHwJ3RE" : 29,
  "-MapysD9wiCqsMGw6245" : 29
},
"tanggalwaktu" : "2021-05-26 12:45:23",
"tayam" : 4000
```

}
}

Comment: If you are getting [object object], it means you are getting the data either in array or object format, not in string format. You need to use JSON.parse(property which gives you object object) say JSON.parse(Sensor) and display the property value.

Comment: how do i put JSON.Parse in my code?

Comment: You shouldn't need to explicitly parse it, but you will need to handle the structure i your code. Can you edit your question to show the data from `/Sensor` in your database? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: ok sir, I have edited my question

Comment: can you please edit your question so the Firebase structure is readable instead of one long string of text?

Comment: oke sir, i have edited my question

Comment: please, help me sir

Comment: What you're trying to read or do with that data is a bit unclear. For example, this code `var statusSensor = f_database.ref("Sensor");` set up a reference to `Sensor` and all of the data is read `.on("value"`. So that data contains child nodes like gas, hayam and kelembaban. What are you attempting to do from there?

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your issue in https://jsfiddle.net/z9o5tgch/1/

```
var suhu = snapshot.child("Sensor/suhu").val();

console.log(JSON.parse(suhu)); // this will output the suhu property keys
```

Referring to the JSFIDDLE example, assuming degree is the property key

```
document.getElementById("suhu").innerHTML = suhu.degree + " °C";
```

Since the property is not mentioned in your question, you need to place the proper property key you get by console.